# How to calculate area from only boundaries length without point coordinates

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate polygon area if I have only boundaries lengths?

Let check this simple example:

[image: Simple example]

I have all boundaries length from this picture in the following format:

- K6-K5: 24.15m
- K5-K10: 10.54m
- K10-K7: 23.63m
- K7-K6: 12.29m

What is suitable approach for calculating polygon area?

I think we have only 2 ways:

- Calculate current area of above plot, then scaling up
- Draw a "real polygon" by boundaries lengths, then calculate area on "real polygon"

Is there another approach for getting more suitable and accurate way?

Comment: How you want to calculate the area? Manually? Using a software? Which one?

Comment: Do you have data on the angles?

Comment: @babel I prefer by manually or by programming, or by python libraries

Comment: @Erik Sorry, but we don't have data on the angles. We can calculate it from above picture, but i don't think i will be accurate

Comment: @Taras Brahmagupta's formula only works for cyclic quadrilateral, and in my case, it is a polygon (may be not quadrilateral, it can have N edges)

Comment: If your question is more about the formula how to calculate the area of (any) irregular rectangle, it's probably off topic for GIS SE, you might be better off here: https://math.stackexchange.com/ or google for calculate area irregular rectangle - plenty of explanations and online tools out there, two of them in the comment by @Taras

Comment: @Taras and i dont think we should split into smaller triangles like this suggestion( http://www.fao.org/3/R7021E/r7021e06.htm ). Because we don't have height of any triangles in real lengths, and calculating it from plot may be not accurate

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://www.squarefootagearea.com/calculator/area-of-irregular-shape/

Comment: @babel But your approach still need to split into smaller triangles, but we don't have real lengths of missing triangle, and calculating it from plot won't be accurate

Comment: Maybe a similar or the same question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/area-of-an-irregular-polygon-using-side-lengths

Comment: If you know the length of one diagonal then you can calculate the area of the two triangles from side lengths and perimeter using Heron's formula: https://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html
Otherwise the task is undefined, several polygons exist with the same side lengths (except triangles).